# How can I make some divs align on a nav?

Tags: html, css, header, nav

This is my first post on stack overflow, so if I do something wrong please inform me :).

This is the HTML:

```
<nav>
<div><img src="images/logo.png"</div>
<div>Noticias</div>
<div>Eventos</div>
<div>Alumnos</div>
<div>Contacto</div>
 </nav>
<div id="content">
<h3><span class="green">Noticias |</span> Los comunicados y anuncios <span class="green">oficales</span> de la institución</h3>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec magna pulvinar, posuere lacus nec, suscipit risus. Nunc vitae sollicitudin nisl.</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa);     *{border:1px dotted black;}

html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    min-height: 2000px;

}

body {
    color: #1F4F75;
    font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    height: 10%;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
}

nav div {
    display: block;
    float:right;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;

}

nav:first-child {
    float:left;
}

#content {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 7%;


}
.green {
    color:#91BA30;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #1F4F75;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LuTLm/ .

My nav has 5 elements: an image and four links. I'm trying to make the apear aligned on the navigation bar, with every element floating to the right, exept the first one (the image) wich floats left and should be resized to fit on the 10% nav.

This shoul be pretty basic. I'm just starting to code web. Alternatives are also welcome as long as they are a actual better solutions.

Comment: In the JS Fiddle I just closed the img tag and it lined up for me.. <div><img src="images/logo.png" /> </div>  added in the "/>"

Comment: Try with `<ul><li>` [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LuTLm/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the bit about floating the img left..

clean up the html to close off the IMG tag with /> and then either add a class or inline css to float the div containing the img to the left..

```
<div style='float:left'><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
```

or

```
<div class='FloatLeft'><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>

.FloatLeft
{
  float: left;
}
```

or
 change the css like this

```
nav div:first-child {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: personally, I'd rather add a class to the div I want to specifically float left.  That way I can do it again to another element if I need to, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, The whole problem was the image tag, duhh. Great to know I get so much help here!

Answer (score 0):

Just update yuor css from

```
nav:first-child {
    float:left;
}
```

to

```
nav div:first-child {
    float:left; // make it float left
    width: 10%; // resize it to 10% width
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/LuTLm/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS tables to do navigation bars. I've found they have a lot of nice properties, such as filling up the full width with evenly spaced navigation items, and are [well supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-table). They even work well with all sorts of semantic markup, including links of lists.

Given the HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div>Noticias</div>
        <div>Eventos</div>
        <div>Alumnos</div>
        <div>Contacto</div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">

<h3><span class="green">Noticias |</span> Los comunicados y anuncios <span class="green">oficales</span> de la institución</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec magna pulvinar, posuere lacus nec, suscipit risus. Nunc vitae sollicitudin nisl.</p>
```

You would use the following CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa);
 html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 2000px;
}
body {
    color: #1F4F75;
    font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
}
nav {
    height: 10%;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
}
nav div {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav div:first-child {
    width: 10%;
}
#content {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
.green {
    color:#91BA30;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #1F4F75;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LuTLm/7/)